# NSUserDefaults with time floats

Tags: ios, objective-c, floating-point, nsuserdefaults

I'm making a game in which the user must complete a task as quickly as possible, and I would like to display the user's best time and update the best time when he or she achieves a new one. I have:

```
float BestTimeValue
float starttime
-(void)start{
starttime += 0.001;
timelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", starttime];
}
if (starttime < BestTimeValue) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:starttime forKey:[@"BestTimeValue"];
}
```

and in my viewdidload:

```
BestTimeValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"BestTimeSaved"];
```

starttime stops when the game is over, but the value won't display in the label. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `float` with the `setObject:forKey:` and `objectForKey:` methods.

Use `setFloat:forKey:` and `floatForKey:`.

```
if (starttime < BestTimeValue) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:starttime forKey:[@"BestTimeValue"];
}


BestTimeValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"BestTimeSaved"];
```

Comment: Even using that syntax, the value won't store. Do I need to set some large value for BestTimeValue first? Because is it so that BestTimeValue is defaulted to a value of zero, in which case starttime  < BestTimeValue will never be true?

Comment: Are you killing the app in the debugger shortly after this code runs? If so, the values in `NSUserDefaults` are not being persisted before you kill the app. Add a call to `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefault] synchronize]` after calling `setFloat:forKey:`.

Comment: I added the synchronize, and the value still won't store in the label. I'm not sure what's wrong, because my code works fine for when I want to store a high score, meaning a value that is HIGHER than the previously stored value.

Comment: It's hard to say what the problem is then. You don't provide any context for the two bits of code you posted in your question. Without more details and knowing what the values are, there's no way to provide further help.

Answer (score 0):

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: forKey:] As the name says, it only accept object like NSString, NSNumber, NSDictionary, etc.

So you have to use other method [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat: forKey] or save the float in a NSNumber to use the setObjet Method [NSNumber numberWithFloat:thefloat];

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't repeat existing answers unless your answer provides additional useful details now found in other answers.