# NSUserDefaults float time value not saving

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to make a game in which the user completes a task in the fastest time possible, and I want to display the user's best time, and update it every time he gets a better time. I have the following code. How do I ensure BestTimeValue isn't always setting to zero?

```
float starttime
float BestTimeValue
-(void)timer2{
starttime = 0.0f;
timer2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1/1000.0f
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(start)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES]; }
-(void)start{
starttime += 0.001;
timelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.3f", starttime];
}




 - (void)viewDidLoad
{

BestTimeValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] floatForKey:@"BestTimeSaved"];
BestTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Best Time: %.3f", BestTimeValue]; }
```

And when the game ends:

```
[timer2 invalidate];
if (starttime < BestTimeValue) {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setFloat:starttime forKey:@"BestTimeSaved"];
}
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Comment: _not displaying_ ? you mean the label is not visible or the value is wrong?

Comment: sorry for not clarifying. the label is visible, but it keeps displaying 0.000

Comment: Isn't this a repeat of [yesterday's question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591241/nsuserdefaults-with-time-floats)? Why post another? Update your previous with more details if needed.

Comment: `if (starttime < BestTimeValue)` you set it when new value is lower, is this what you want? if `starttime` is a positive number, the best time will always be 0

Comment: didn't realize i could edit my question after posting! yes i want the new value to set when it is lower, how can i make it so best time will actually be the user's best time in completing the task?